# vue-ssr report some strong error when first render

Tags: vuejs2, vue-ssr

[image]

When i link / first time, it will redirect to /home, it's ok. But i link /home first time, it give me the error below. please help me.

Comment: Can you some some of the code in that the router uses?

Comment: em. Thanks a lot, i had resolved it.

Comment: You should outline the steps you used to resolve it. That will help the next person.

Comment: I use the lodash plugin which is commonjs style.

Comment: You just had to lodash in `package.json` ?

Comment: No, lodash has two module style